# Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipeline - Azure Function to 2 different Function Apps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I've got a GitHub Repo with some source code in it for an Azure function.
The Repo requires a approval on a pull request to push changes into the "Main" branch.

I'm trying to set up an Azure DevOps pipeline that will;

1. Deploy to azurefunctionurl1.net est is initiated.
2. Once the pull request is approved and the changes hit the main branch deploy to azurefunctionurl1.net
3. Package up all waiting changes for each deployment into batches
4. Exclude changes to the documentation folder

I'm struggling to build the yaml file.
I think I need;

```
trigger:
  Batch: true
  Branches: 
    Include:
     - master
  Paths:
    exclude:
     - docs/
```

I feel like I need a stage or gate so that when the pull request is closed it does the same step to the second url.

Can anyone lend a hand?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need stages or gates and your YAML script looks well in structure.

However, there are three places to note:

1. Yaml is case sensitive, and its reserved strings should be lowercase.
2. In your step 2 you mentioned `main` branch, but in YAML script you are using `master` branch. Note that the branch in YAML script should correspond to your actual branch.
3. There should be no `\` after a path. If you want to specify all files in the `docs` folder, `docs` will do the job.

This is my modified script:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches: 
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    exclude:
    - docs
```